# Is it possible use include() twice in a php page?

Tags: php

Can we use include(page.php) two times in a php page.Any possibilities for errors

Eg:

```
include(page.php);
 -------
--------
--------
--------
include(page.php);
```

Comment: Ya it is possible. But the 2nd will overwrites the first. If you dont want it then use include_once.

Comment: @issueNo329, what do you mean the 2nd will overwrite the first?

Comment: I think this is trivial enough to write and test it yourself. I bet you will learn your way faster than the folks here in SO will answer - meaning, they will first have to read the question and take time write an answer

Comment: If you have executed include(something.php) and then redirecting your page to another page, and you are having same include(something.php) statement, then the second call is applicable for redirected file. Else if you are using include_once(something.php) in redirected page, then the second call will not be executes.

Comment: Yes it's possible. You should have just tried it rather than asking the question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because user could have got the answser by just running the code in the question.

Comment: i want to know the possible errors.

Comment: @Spudley I wanted to know it without testing. Its faster to search for the question than testing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes it is possible.

But it can have some adverse effects on your code.

---

Consider this...

**`test1.php`**

```
<?php
$var=1;
```

**`test2.php`**

```
<?php
include('test1.php');
echo $var; // "prints" 1
$var = 30;
include('test1.php');
echo $var; // "prints" 1 again.
```

To overcome this situation , you should make use of **`include_once()`** construct.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can include as many times as you wish. Although instead of asking, you could try it and find out yourself.

**warning**

If there are any definitions (like classes) inside it - you will get an error regarding its redefinition.

Answer (score 4):

Yes but if you have defined any class or function in that file then it will be redefined and PHP throws error.

Answer (score 1):

Ya it is possible. But the 2nd will overwrites the first. If you dont want it then use include_once.

Comment: What do you mean by "overwrite"? If the included file contains `echo microtime(true);` both will be displayed with different content. So what has been "overwritten"?

Comment: What I meant was variables, echo is something which given to the output buffer, you can check Shankar Damodaran ans above.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can include as many times as you wish.