# fetch() is closing the mysqli connection

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a problem in my php that I need to include all the time the config.php (mysqli php connection script)

```
<?php

$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 
include("$root/config.php"); // INCLUDE CONFIG

$stmt = $mysqli_link->prepare("SELECT id, categoria FROM categoria order by rand() limit 10");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id1, $categoria);


include("$root/config.php"); // NEED TO INCLUDE CONFIG AGAIN TO AVOID - Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param()


while($stmt->fetch()) {

$stmt2 = $mysqli_link->prepare("SELECT id, categoria, cover, fotos, titulo, descricao, data FROM posts where categoria = ? order by id desc limit 1");
$stmt2->bind_param('i', $id1);
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->bind_result($id, $categoria, $cover, $pictures, $titulo, $descricao, $data);
$stmt2->fetch();

    echo"<li class=liside><img src=/$picture class=row><a href=/category/$categorialink>$categoria</a></li>";
}

?>
```

What am I doing wrong? I need first the $stmt to select categories, after that $stmt2 inside while to get things from that category on post table.

config.php

```
$hostname="localhost";
$titulo="config";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$bd="site";

$mysqli_link = new mysqli($hostname, $user, $pass, $bd);
$mysqli_link->set_charset("utf8");
ini_set('default_charset','utf8');
```

Comment: Why do you think you're getting Fatal when trying to call bind_param? Because I think that second include call have something to do with it.

Comment: maybe some function is closing $mysqli_link... I need to add config.php before while to avoid that error.

Comment: Can you show config.php? I was think on something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232784/is-it-possible-use-include-twice-in-a-php-page)...

Comment: What's the error you see if you remove the 2nd `include("$root/config.php")` call?  Because the `$mysqli_link` is not being closed, there's probably just a SQL error.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param()

Comment: @renatacosta: Do you mean "call to *undefined* member function"?  Can you paste **exact** error?  That message is missing a few words.

Comment: ... of a non-object? It means your `$stmt2` isn't receving return from your prepare.

Comment: @renatacosta: it's unrelated to the question, but it would be way better if you make a single query, joining categoria and posts, instead of looping.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-include\side.php on line 35

Comment: `var_dump($stmt2)` and see what you get. Probably `false`

Comment: P.S. You don't need to call `$stmt2 = $mysqli_link->prepare("SELECT ...");` in the loop.  You can prepare it once outside the loop along with `$stmt2->bind_param` and `$stmt2->bind_result()`.  Then in the loop, all you need is `execute` and `fetch`.

Comment: line 17 in this code

Comment: @renatacosta: That means `->prepare()` returned `false`.  What does `var_dump($mysqli_link->error)` show you after declaring `$stmt2`?

Comment: BTW, no need to double-set charset

Comment: var_dump show me: string(52) "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" is it right?

Comment: @renatacosta: Is what right?  That's the ***actual*** error/issue here.

Comment: [There is a question talking about it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614671/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now)

Comment: bool(false) = var_dump($stmt2);

Comment: And seems to be related what @RocketHazmat told, you should loop over result and not execution.

Comment: @AedixRhinedale: What I said isn't really the solution, just a suggestion to optimize this.

Comment: @RocketHazmat as far as I understood, the subsequent exec() callings inside while loop is just what's causing this

Comment: As @AedixRhinedale said, I saw the other post about this and the solution appears to be to add $stmt->store_result() instead of the second config.php...

Comment: Well then @renatacosta you try it and tell us what you've got :)

Comment: @renatacosta: Yes, that should be the solution.  Re-`including` your config.php "fixed" it by opening a 2nd MySQL connection for the 2nd query.  No reason to need 2 MySQL connections.

Comment: @RocketHazmat thank you! and thank you all friends. the answer solution works nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have 2 queries running at the same time and MySQLi doesn't like that.  Your `include("$root/config.php");` "fixed" it because it opened a 2nd MySQL connection for the 2nd query to run.

This is not suggested, and the solution is that you need to "buffer" the results of the 1st query so that MySQL can run the other(s).  The [`store_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php) should fix this.

See this question for more info: [Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614671/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now)

Also, as a suggestion, you only need to `prepare()` a query once.  You can re-use it.

So, try this:

```
<?php

$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 
include("$root/config.php"); // INCLUDE CONFIG

$stmt = $mysqli_link->prepare("SELECT id, categoria FROM categoria order by rand() limit 10");
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($id1, $categoria);
$stmt->store_result();  // Added to buffer result set

// You can re-use the same prepared statment in a loop
$stmt2 = $mysqli_link->prepare("SELECT id, categoria, cover, fotos, titulo, descricao, data FROM posts where categoria = ? order by id desc limit 1");
$stmt2->bind_param('i', $id1);
$stmt2->bind_result($id, $categoria, $cover, $pictures, $titulo, $descricao, $data);

while($stmt->fetch()){
    $stmt2->execute();
    $stmt2->fetch();

    echo"<li class=liside><img src=/$picture class=row><a href=/category/$categorialink>$categoria</a></li>";
}

// You should close your statements when you're done with them
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
$stmt2->close();

?>
```

P.S. There's no real need to run 2 (or more) queries here.  You can get what you want with just one.  You just need to `JOIN` the tables.

Note: This might not work 100%, but it's just a suggestion of how to clean up this code and run less queries.

```
<?php

$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 
include("$root/config.php"); // INCLUDE CONFIG

$stmt = $mysqli_link->prepare("
    SELECT categoria.id, categoria.categoria,
        posts.id, posts.categoria, posts.cover, posts.fotos, posts.titulo, posts.descricao, posts.data
    FROM categoria
    JOIN posts ON posts.categoria = categoria.id
    GROUP BY categoria.id
    ORDER BY rand()
    LIMIT 10
");

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id1, $categoria, $id, $posts_categoria, $cover, $pictures, $titulo, $descricao, $data);

while($stmt->fetch()){
    echo"<li class=liside><img src=/$picture class=row><a href=/category/$categorialink>$categoria</a></li>";
}


$stmt->close();
?>
```

Comment: oh, this works nice! the only problem is the select is getting the same category many times...

Comment: i think group by posts.categoria solve this! thank you friend

Comment: @renatacosta: Yeah, I wasn't too sure about the `JOIN`ed query.  That was more of a suggestion than a correct answer.  Glad you got it working :-)